Buildroot /etc/init.d/rcS error : file S98modules: not found
I'm working on a linux system using buildroot. I have implemented using the rootfs overlay the script to launch a kernel driver. The script is named S98modules. I did the make to compile the filesystem and I verified it using QEMU.
At the startup of QEMU I see the error message: /etc/init.d/rcS: line 23 /etc/init.d/S98modules: not found
I checked and I found that the file is present.
Where could be the error?

The owner is root:root and the permission are 755.
In any case, I found the problem: it was a hidden character I was not seeing using gedit.
I removed it using the command:
Sed -i 's/r$\\/' filename
Claudio

I suppose it's because your script is not executable (i.e it doesn't have the execute permissions)
